# Where is the supported graphics card list by bumblebee project?

Tags: bumblebee

I want to get the latest list.

I can't find it on main page of bumblebee.

Is that support GTX670M?

Thank you~

Comment: I think, bumblebee requires the `nvidia-current` driver. This driver is responsible for supporting graphics chip. Bumblebee support every optimus system as long there is no architectural change. But the driver in ubuntu may not support new chips. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/

Comment: Though I am not sure. Lets wait for a better answer.

Comment: Where is the supported driver list by ubuntu not bumblebee? Thank you~

Comment: You can see it in [Certified hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/make/NVIDIA%20Corporation/?page=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the  [Bumblebee-Project FAQ page](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ).

> How to know if my graphics card is supported?
>
> Bumblebee has two parts: power management and the ability to run
>   programs using the discrete card. The first feature is supported with
>   bbswitch which should be able to support all Optimus models. The
>   **ability to use the nvidia card depends on the driver:** [open-source nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix) and
>   [proprietary
>   nvidia.](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=122606).

And from the proprietary nvidia page  it does seems to support  as

[302.17 for Linux x86/x86_64 released
Release highlights since 302.11:](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=2564603)

```
Added support for the following GPUs:

    GeForce GTX 670M
```